# access function not returning Either Failure a

Tags: mongodb, haskell, types, type-inference

I am having some difficulty with the Haskell mongoDB driver and the return type of the `access` function. According to [the hackage documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-1.3.2/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#access) and [the tutorial on the haskell-mongodb github page](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md#action-monad), `access` should have the type

```
MonadIO m => Pipe -> AccessMode -> Database -> Action m a -> m (Either Failure a)
```

However, in the type inference in my code, a local Hoogle query, and [the source code](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/blob/master/Database/MongoDB/Query.hs#L118), there is no either involved. They are all showing the type

```
MonadIO m => Pipe -> AccessMode -> Database -> Action m a -> m a
```

I am still pretty new to Haskell so I hesitate to jump to the conclusion that the writers of the documentation were wrong, but from my frustrated perspective that feels like the case.

**Is this monad/kind trickery, am I misreading the documentation, or is the documentation incorrect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by version mismatch. Version [1.3.2 on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/blob/1.3.2/Database/MongoDB/Query.hs#L114) also has `Either` in the return type.

Comment: And [the current documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-2.2.0/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#g:1) does not, although the tutorial and the comment on the current version still reference an `Either` return type. As of posting, this is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/issues/67). Thanks for pointing that out.